# Is there a way to set minimum date on input to work on iOS?

Tags: ios, angularjs, validation, date, cross-platform

I am developing a cross-platform mobile application in AngularJS at first for iOS and I would like to set the minimum date on the built-in iOS datepickor to a specific date, in order not to let the user select invalid dates.

The input in my view looks like this:

```
<input type="date" class="date-button" ng-min="2015-12-09" ng-model="arrivalDate"/>
```

I've tried either setting the `min="2015-12-09"` attribute, but non of the options worked. I've read that it is not even possible to alter the Safari built-in datepicker, however if there is a way to make it work, I would be eager to know.

Comment: cross-platform with which processor? Cordova? Phonegap (that is same as cordova?)

Comment: I am using Onsen UI (http://onsen.io/), which runs on cordova, however phonegap is almost the same as cordova as it reuses it's libraries.

Comment: almost is incorrect. By now cordova IS phonegap. But, this is off-topic. I am sorry i never used onsen, I think I can't help you.